# Store class name into a const global variable at compile time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ld, dyld, mach-o

I know `__attribute((used, section("__DATA,SectionName")))` can be used to declare a variable stored in one section. So I want to use this to store some special classes[confirm to a `protocol`] to one section, and retrieve them at runtime.

I can do it with a macro accept a class name, but this will has no check for the existence of the class.

So how can I retrieve the class name at compile time and store it to a global variable?

---

Explain my thought more detail.

I need the class name at compile time, because I want to store some special classes into one section. And then use these names to reflect the class by `NSClassFromString`. More like register the classes into a special section at compile time not at runtime.

In my opinion class name is like a constant string, why can't have variable point to it? 
In c we can declare a global variable like this:

```
void * test = &open;
```

Can we do something similar to the class in OC?

Comment: why you need your class name at compile time ??? you mean runtime getting class name ?

Comment: @CodeChanger +1 Plus: You cannot know at compile time, whether a class will exist at runtime. Therefore *but this will has no check for the existence of the class* seems to be senseless.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I have add more info about this questions.

Comment: The added information doesn't change anything. Why can't you do the assignment at program start-up? However, in C `void * test = &open`  does not store any identifier and does completely nothing at compile time – except of being compiled.